# How can I return value of a column based on the min value of one column and max value of another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Supposing I have a df like the following,

```
column1 | column2 | column3  |column4  | column5 
A       |    B    |    5     |   4234  |   123   
A       |    B    |    2     |   432   |   3243  
A       |    B    |    10    |   123   |   43    
A       |    B    |    1     |   123   |   45    
A       |    B    |    1     |   124   |   23243 
A       |    B    |    1     |   125   |   234   
A       |    B    |    1     |   126   |   23
```

**Note: column4 is always unique**

Desired df,

```
column1 | column2 | column3  |column4  | column5 |column6
A       |    B    |    5     |   4234  |   123   |
A       |    B    |    2     |   432   |   3243  |
A       |    B    |    10    |   123   |   43    |
A       |    B    |    1     |   123   |   45    | 
A       |    B    |    1     |   124   |   23243 | 
A       |    B    |    1     |   125   |   234   |
A       |    B    |    1     |   126   |   23    | 23
```

I want to be able to groupby on the basis of column1 and column2, find the min value of column3 (in this case -> 1) followed by finding the max value of column4 (in this case -> 126) and return its corresponding column6 value (in this case -> 23).

Step 1 -> find the min value for a given [['column1', 'column2']] that is 1

```
column1 | column2 | column3      |column4  | column5 |column6
A       |    B    |    5         |         |   123   |
A       |    B    |    2         |         |   3243  |
A       |    B    |    10        |         |   43    |
A       |    B    |    **1**     |   123   |   45    | 
A       |    B    |    **1**     |   124   |   23243 | 
A       |    B    |    **1**     |   125   |   234   |
A       |    B    |    **1**     |   126   |   23    | 23
```

Step 2

find the max value of column 4 for a given [['column1', 'column2', 'column3']]

```
column1 | column2 | column3  |column4      | column5 |column6
A       |    B    |    5     |             |   123   |
A       |    B    |    2     |             |   3243  |
A       |    B    |    10    |             |   43    |
A       |    B    |    1     |   123       |   45    | 
A       |    B    |    1     |   124       |   23243 | 
A       |    B    |    1     |   125       |   234   |
A       |    B    |    1     |   **126**   |   23    | 23
```

Step 3 return the corresponding value of column5 that is 23

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The maximum value of ```column4``` would be 4234, not 126.

Comment: no you take the minimum value of column3 first(that is 1) so you're left with 123,124,125,126 out of which 126 is the biggest value

Comment: May get you closer... `df[df['column4'] == df.loc[df['column3'] == df['column3'].min(), 'column4'].max()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1":["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
    "column2":["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "column3":[5, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "column4":[4234, 432, 123, 123, 124, 125, 126],
    "column5":[123, 3243, 43, 45, 23243, 234, 23]
})

df

    column1     column2     column3     column4     column5
0   A              B          5            4234       123
1   A              B          2            432        3243
2   A              B          10           123        43
3   A              B          1            123        45
4   A              B          1            124        23243
5   A              B          1            125        234
6   A              B          1            126        23

row_index = df.loc[df["column3"]==(df.groupby(["column1", "column2"])["column3"].min()).min()]["column4"].idxmax()
val_index = df["column5"].iloc[(df.loc[df["column3"]==(df.groupby(["column1", "column2"])["column3"].min()).min()]["column4"].idxmax())]

df.loc[row_index, "column6"] = val_index

df
    column1     column2     column3     column4     column5     column6
0   A               B           5       4234        123         NaN
1   A               B           2       432         3243        NaN
2   A               B           10      123         43          NaN
3   A               B           1       123         45          NaN
4   A               B           1       124         23243       NaN
5   A               B           1       125         234         NaN
6   A               B           1       126         23          23.0
```

If you want it in one line

```
df.loc[df.loc[df["column3"]==(df.groupby(["column1", "column2"])["column3"].min()).min()]["column4"].idxmax(), "column6"] = df["column5"].iloc[(df.loc[df["column3"]==(df.groupby(["column1", "column2"])["column3"].min()).min()]["column4"].idxmax())]
```

Another option

```
df.loc[(df[df['column4'] == df.loc[df['column3'] == df['column3'].min(), 'column4'].max()]["column5"]).index, "column6"] = df[df['column4'] == df.loc[df['column3'] == df['column3'].min(), 'column4'].max()]["column5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

- find the rows with the min of **column3** `df.loc[df["column3"].eq(df["column3"].min())]`
- of these rows find rows with max of **column4**
- rename and join back together

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""column1 | column2 | column3  |column4  | column5 
A       |    B    |    5     |   4234  |   123   
A       |    B    |    2     |   432   |   3243  
A       |    B    |    10    |   123   |   43    
A       |    B    |    1     |   123   |   45    
A       |    B    |    1     |   124   |   23243 
A       |    B    |    1     |   125   |   234   
A       |    B    |    1     |   126   |   23   """), sep="|").pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c:c.strip() for c in d.columns}))


df.groupby(["column1", "column2"], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda df: df.join(
        df.loc[df["column3"].eq(df["column3"].min())]
        .loc[lambda d: d["column4"].eq(d["column4"].max()), "column5"]
        .rename("column6")
    )
)
```

|  | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | B | 5 | 4234 | 123 | nan |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 432 | 3243 | nan |
| 2 | A | B | 10 | 123 | 43 | nan |
| 3 | A | B | 1 | 123 | 45 | nan |
| 4 | A | B | 1 | 124 | 23243 | nan |
| 5 | A | B | 1 | 125 | 234 | nan |
| 6 | A | B | 1 | 126 | 23 | 23 |

Comment: think group by is necessary here for column1 and column2 because it will always find the least value of column 3 and so on, right?

Comment: your question hs been made less ambiguous than when it was first started, yes. updated

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to groupby 2 times:

```
minval=df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column3'].min().tolist()
maxval=df.loc[df['column3'].isin(minval)].groupby(['column1','column2'])['column4'].max().tolist()
df['column6']=df['column5'].where(df['column4'].isin(maxval))
```

output of `df`:

```
  column1 column2  column3  column4  column5  column6
0       A       B        5     4234      123      NaN
1       A       B        2      432     3243      NaN
2       A       B       10      123       43      NaN
3       A       B        1      123       45      NaN
4       A       B        1      124    23243      NaN
5       A       B        1      125      234      NaN
6       A       B        1      126       23     23.0
```